# Xsel behavior on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, clipboard, clipboard-interaction

Is there a way to get the selected text in OS X like the app `xsel` does in Linux? I've searched here and the `pbpaste` is equal to `xsel --clipboard`, because the user need to execute ⌘+C to copy the text to clipboard. But similar to the `xsel`, just putting the text in a different buffer by simply selecting it, i've not found. Is there a way? Any app?A OS X Configuration?

Comment: Selections are an X-specific facility.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Which are the GUI toolkit for OS X? Is not equal to the X-Window?

Comment: OS X has used [Aqua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_%28user_interface%29) since... ever.